# Using different classes to check on main form controls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, subclass, public-method

I'm struggling to wrap my head around a concept and I've been at this for 4-5 hours now. So I'm hoping that someone can explain this to me.

I have multiple checkboxes inside a tabpage labeled "tabpage2" on the main form "QoE" and I have multiple classes that need to know the check states of those checkboxes.

I first went about this using:

```
dim f as new QoE
```

in each class, then calling the checkboxes like this:

```
f.chkTcpRTT.checked
```

but the result is always coming back "False" whether the box is checked or not, which I am assuming has to do with the fact that I am using the word "new".

My second thought was to use the property method

```
Public Shared Property getchecker(ByVal chk As CheckBox) As Boolean
    Get
        Return chk.Checked
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        chk.Checked = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But this still leaves me with having to pass an object from the other class which I cant figure out. so I tried this:

```
Public Shared Property getchecker(ByVal txt As string) As Boolean
    Get
        For Each ctrl as Control in TabPage2.Controls
            If ctrl.name = txt Then
                 Return ctrl.Checked
            End If
        Next
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        txt.Checked = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But now I am getting the error: "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class."

The methods that I am using to call these features are all "public shared" so why am I getting this error and how can I get these checkstates? If its possible I would like to use some variation of the first code, so why is everything coming back false? is it because of the "new" flag? I would love to know a little background if its possible.

Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call controls from other classes you have to initiate the form and all the controls.

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Shared f as Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       f = Me
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in other classes just refer to f normally like

```
Form1.f.Textbox1.Text = ""
```

or

```
Form1.f.CheckBox1.Checked = True
```

Enjoy

For some additional reading:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?744677-RESOLVED-Struggling-with-trying-to-access-a-control-on-a-form-from-seperate-classes&p=4563273&highlight=#post4563273

Comment: Not a great solution. f is null in your example. What happens if you have two Form1s open?

Comment: Like I said in the last post - You really should give it a try first. I'm currently using this in two of my programs.

Comment: Not trolling, just saw you post the exact same answer, so I posted the exact same comment.  :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry, i deleted that, and I also added some extra reading and some other options

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `TabPage2` is an instance variable, yet you are trying to reference `TabPage2` from a `Shared` method where `TabPage2` doesn't exist.

You need to remove the `Shared` modifier on the `getchecker` method.

---

Response re comments.

Try something like this:

```
Public Property getchecker(ByVal txt As string) As Boolean
    For Each ctrl as Control in Me.TabPage2.Controls
        If ctrl.name = txt Then
                Return ctrl.Checked
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Property
```

To use this you would pass your reference of `f` to the other class and it would call it like so `f.getchecker("foo")`.

Comment: Tabpage2 is a container that contains 6 checkboxes, its a tabpage from a TAB control object.... Also, without the shared, how would I call the property from another class ? ... Plus I would have to pass it a checkbox object, how do I reference a checkbox from another class in the first place?

Comment: You can set the access modifier of the checkboxes to `public` and then you can access them from your main window as well (through the instance variable `tabpage2`).

Comment: They have been set to public this entire time, and so is the tab container. I still cant seem to access them in anyway

Comment: You would need to pass a reference to the form to allow access. At the end of the day you need to pass some reference around to do what you want. A shared method has no idea of any instances of the class without being passed a reference.

Comment: Can you post some code? and I thought dim f as new QoE was passing a reference?

Comment: `Dim f As New QoE` is creating the reference, not passing it. I've added some code to my answer.

Comment: Sorry im still just not getting this, so I have a few more questions... If i put that code that you posted in my "QoE" Form, how can I access it in another class without it being "Public Shared" instead of just Public? Currently I cannot see it in any other class but the "QoE" class in which it is written. Second question, when I can see it in a separate class, how would i initialize it in that class? QoE.GetChecker(whatHere?, "chkTCPRTT")?

Comment: but then how do you initialize f?

Comment: Just as you did - `Dim f As New QoE`.